# Shell script not running on Mac OS

Tags: bash, shell

I have what amounts to a very simple bash script that executes a deployment. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function print_help
{
  echo '
     Deploy the application.

   Usage:
    -r          reinstall
    -h          show help
    '
}

reinstall=false
while getopts "rh" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    r)
      echo "clean"
      reinstall=true
      ;;
    h)
      echo "help"
      print_help
      exit 0
      ;;
  esac
done
```

I am calling the script as follows:

```
. deploy.sh -h
```

No matter what I do, neither option (i.e. -r, -h) results in the respective `echo` and in the case of `-h` the `print_help` function isn't called.

What am doing wrong?

Comment: You are sourcing the script. Please post the script that is sourcing it. Did you reset getopts environment variables? From the man page `Whenever the shell is invoked, OPTIND shall be initialized to 1.`

Comment: That is my entire script so I guess I am not resetting the vars...

Comment: `I am calling the script as follows:

. deploy.sh -h` - from where are you calling the script?

Comment: Use `./deploy.sh -h`, not `. deploy.sh -h`, to invoke the script *as a separate process* from your interactive shell.

Comment: Ah... I see what the issue is. I am planning on running it from a python script. If I don't source it, it works as expected. My bad.

Comment: As an aside, btw -- see the entry in the last table in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: legacy ksh function declaration syntax. bash supports it (like many other pre-POSIX kshisms) for backwards compatibility; but `print_help() { ...; }` with no preceding `function` should be preferred for new code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Perhaps the script is intended to be sourced, because the invoking process needs to access `reinstall` afterwards. Since arguments can be passed to a _source_ command, at least in newer bash shells (the OP, using MacOS, is perhaps running an old bash), the approach is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: @MoreScratch : Do a `set -x`; echo $BASH_VERSINFO` before you are sourcing your `deploy.sh` and post the outcome.

Comment: @user1934428, arguments can be passed to `source` in bash 3.2 as well. This behavior does not suffer between the version shipped with MacOS and newer releases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Good to know; I thought so, but was not sure. BTW, with displaying BASH_VERSINFO, I want to verify hat this is **really** run from within a bash shell.

Comment: @MoreScratch : You say that this script is supposed to execute a deployment, but there is no code in it which would deploy something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopts` uses a *global variable* `OPTIND` to keep track about which argument it processes currently. Each option it parses, it increments/changes `OPTIND` to keep track which argument will be next.

If you call `getopt` without changing `OPTIND` it will start from where it last ended. If it already parsed first argument, it would want to continue parsing from  the second argument, etc. Because there is no second argument the second (or later) time you source your script, there is only `-h`, `getopt` will just fail, because it thinks it already parsed `-h`.

If you want to re-parse arguments in current shell, you need to just reset `OPTIND=1`. Or start a fresh new shell, which will reset `OPTIND` to `1` by itself.

Comment: in case you call it like that  `. deploy.sh -h` it will kill the current shell as there's an exit 0 in the case switch which is i supose never an expected feature when you print help and make the OPTIND unuseable as you'll have to open a new shell each time you call your script !!

Comment: @Delaballe : I thought the `exit` was deliberately, and the sourcing of the deploy script was done from within some other script, not from the interactive command line (which would not make much sense).

Comment: @user1934428, the code's production use is from Python, per the OP. There's no value to sourcing something into a transient shell subprocess started by a Python interpreter -- and the OP *accepted this answer* as solving their problem. Both support the "not much sense" conclusion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Interesting, where did you see this? I don't  see Python even mentioned in the question, and since we can _source_ a bash-script only either from the bash command line or from within anouther bash-script, I don't understand how Python fills in here; in particular since there is no _Python_ tag in this question.

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked this. Then of course, sourcing does not make any sense at all. And, since this is the **entire** script, as the OP claims, the whole script is meaningless. It does not do anything except writing something to stdout! It just sets a variable which is not used anywhere else.

Comment: @user1934428 I assume the actual work was removed in the name of making it a [mre], since printing help or failing to is sufficient to test whether the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a space between the dot and your script name then you're not lauching the script but just sourcing it to your current shell session !

if you want to run your scipt you should do :

```
# chmod +x ./deploy.sh
# ./deploy.sh -h
```

if you source it the functtions and variables inside your scipt will be available in your current shell session this could allow you to do things like that :

```
# . ./deploy.sh
# print_help
```

Comment: You might speak to *why* sourcing the script causes the OP's symptoms; it's not completely obvious (at least, to someone who hasn't yet read KamilCuk's comment on the question). :)

Comment: ("script will not be executed" is not really true; sourcing a script in *does* execute its contents inside the current shell; The problem is that the OP's code is not idempotent; an interpreter will execute it differently based on whether it's the first invocation or a subsequent one inside the same shell).

Comment: (...which is to say, `. deploy.sh -h` will work as the OP expects, but only exactly once per shell unless `OPTIND` is reset).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy scripts are necessary executed when sourced otherwise any variable in it could not be interpreted i just wanted my aswer to be more understandable as possible

Comment: Understood; but one shouldn't aim for clarity at the expense of correctness -- the "but the script will not be executed" statement is simply wrong. Otherwise someone might think they could source a script to *only* get its function and variable definitions without any other side effects.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in case you call it like that `. deploy.sh -h` it will kill the current shell as there's an exit 0 in the case switch which is i supose never an expected feature when you print help !!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok i removed it